# Propper css and div layout

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a layout where the outer div is 100% width and height. In this div I will add more divs dynamically. I want to write a css structure that splits the outer div so that each div gets the same space. Actually I want to create a dynamic grid with div elements. 
Examples below: 
[image]

Comment: Cool story bro, that you want to build this, but what is exactly the question here???????

Comment: You should also paste some code here so we can see what you already have tried. Honestly, I think no one is willed to do all the work for you.

Comment: The question is: How can i achieve this using correct css style. I didn't paste any code because I only have the outer div with width and height 100% I don' know the style for the the other divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of "Sowmia" is so good but one thing :
you want to sub div have AUTO SIZE and with is solution you can't do this.
my solution is exactly the Sowmia's answer with some changes:

```
<style type="text/css" >
.main{width:100%;  height:100%;  background:#F5D0A9; overflow:auto}
.sub{width:auto;  
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    background:#8181F7;
    margin:4px;  
   border:solid 1px #2ECCFA}
</style>
```

and html:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub">this is div number 1</div>
    <div class="sub">this is div number 2</div>
    <div class="sub">if you have a big text this div is bigger than the other
    <br />
    even you can have a text with some height
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is :
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/talebihamid/4ACU5/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm looking for a sollution not depending on content. Here the content expands the divs.

Comment: @fox,hi,my answer is not dependent to content.please see the CSS property that I wrote .sub{width:auto & height :auto} that means if you write 1 line or 10 line and so on the sub div is auto resize.

Answer (score 0):

with only css its not possible but you can do this with jquery just count div and set their width according to number of div